# Display a custom 3D model in a Mapbox map in Mobile Maps SDK

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

I want to display a custom 3D object (e.g. OBJ, GLTF, GLB...) in a Mapbox map on Android/iOS. Is this possible?

I am not familiar with Mapbox yet, but am considering using it. I tried to Google and search their doc for an answer but couldn't come to a conclusion. I saw:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model-threebox/

But I believe that is for something different (Mapbox GL JS), right? Or does this mean that it is also possible on Android/iOS somehow?